# switch inside while loop - missing return statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

There are many similar topics, but I can't find exactly where my problem is..

CustomerDetails - abstract class

The method reads from a file, where first letter determines the types of a customer (which are sub-classes of CustomerDetails).

```
public static CustomerDetails readCustomerData(....)

   try
   {
        while(...hasNextLine())  
        {
            ..... 
            .....
            switch(firstLetter)
            {
                case 'A':  ....
                           PrivateCustomerDetails aaa = new PrivateCustomerDetails(...   inherited fields + some extra ones)
                          return aaa;

                case 'B': ...  BusinessCustomerDetails bbb = .....
                          return bbb;

                default:  return null;
             }
        }
        // possibly return something here..
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      ...
      return null;
  }
```

I have noticed that if I enter "return null;" at a comment field above, missing return statement disappear. But I cant get why? I have possible scenarios as well as default statement, which covers all other cases.

Moreover, I can't initialize CustomerDetails object, assign new objects of sub-classes to it and return, since it is abstract..

Also, I can't make the names of the objects of sub-classes the same to return it in the end..

Need some clarification.. Thanks very much!

Comment: There seem to be 3 questions here. The first one has been answered. The  other 2 aren't clear. I'd make them separate questions with more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if `hasNextLine()` returns false the very first time you call it? What would be returned in that case? You need a `return` statement to handle that possibility.

If you don't expect that to happen, an alternative is to `throw` an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is possible that the while loop is never executed. In this case you have to return a value.